# How to Report Error of Syntax Analyzer in C++?

Tags: compiler-construction

Hi I am currently making a Syntax Analyzer in C++

Using DFA Table, I already implemented syntax analyzing.

And I have to print the error report when we have error(the error line, and what is error)

Now, my program just know we have error.(when dfa table is empty in this state)

**I don't have any idea about how to know the type of syntax error in my input code (ex) line 11 : missing rparen)**

Help me

Comment: Are you using an LL(1) or LR parser?

Comment: @Xilpex LR parser

Answer (score 0):

So to do that, you have to gear your lexical analyzer with line (and maybe position) info. For example, `(` as a token would normally be:

```
<TOKEN_RPAREN>
```

but you've got to make that:

```
<TOKEN_RPAREN, 11>
```

where `11` is the line number the token was seen at. Now that you have the line number, whenever you run into an error, you have the line number where the error was hit. As for identifying the error type, in the table, instead of putting a blank entry for errors, you could put an error message.